# Why did my teacher come to this solution , (probability)?

Tags: probability

Here is the problem :
In a box there are 10 balls with number from 1 to 10.If randomly 6 balls are withdrawn . What is the probability that among the withdrawn balls we get 
a) the ball with number 1 and b) the balls with numbers 1 and 2 .

For a) she solved like this 
$P=\frac{\binom{9}{5}}{\binom{10}{6}} =\frac{126}{210}=0.6$

and for b)

$P=\frac{\binom{8}{4}}{\binom{10}{6}} =\frac{70}{210}=0.3333$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are only interested in the numbers of the balls, the order does not matter. Consider the event that the ball with number $1$ is withdrawn among the $6$ balls. That means that one ball is fixed (this is the ball with number $1$) and $5$ balls can be chosen freely. There are ${9\choose 5}$ ways to choose $5$ balls out of $9$ balls when the order is not important. We need to divide ${9\choose 5}$ by the number of ways to choose $6$ balls out of $10$ when the order is not important.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I need a better understanding of combinations